# Regex to remove first set of zeros

Tags: python, regex

I have the following example string and I would like to remove only one set of zeros.

The example string is

> AAL000007200100000787777388300000

I would like to remove only the first set of zero's and leave the rest intact.  I want to end up with

> AAL7200100000787777388300000

I have tried the following but it is always too greedy and takes the second set of zeros as well!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

suffixdrop = re.split("\B0+\B", "AAL000007200100000787777388300000", re.I)
if suffixdrop: #found a suffix here
        print(suffixdrop)
```

The result of the print is

> ['AAL', '72', '100000787777388300000']

Comment: this is a really small thing, but there's an unwanted space in the middle of "suffixdrop" at `print(suffix drop)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\B` matches the opposite of word boundaries, which doesn't sound like what you want here.

If you want to remove the first set of consecutive 0's after a non-digit character, try this:

```
In [7]: print x
AAL000007200100000787777388300000

In [8]: print re.sub("^(\D+)0+", r"\1", x)
AAL7200100000787777388300000
```

`re.sub("^(\D+)0+", r"\1", x)` means "match the start of the line followed by any number of non-digit characters, followed by any number of 0 characters" and replace it with the first group of non-digit characters.

Comment: Thanks Matt, and a very comprehensive answer!  This is exactly what I was after!

Comment: Note that I edited out the stuff about using a lookbehind as what I posted originally would also have replaced any second set of repeating 0's if they also followed a non-digit character, for example if you had `AL000007B003` the output would have been `AL7B3`

Comment: Yeah thanks, saw you did that as I was doing it.  The look behind was useful though to see.  I will accept the answer when it lets me!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
re.sub(r'0+', '', "AAL000007200100000787777388300000", count=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

replace match of regex `(?<=^\D*?)(0+)(?=.*$)` with empty string